# Weekly SO digest with comments? What say you?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

How about this idea:

A free-formed collection of volunteer gurus pull up interesting answers within a week and provide brief commentary (why this is interesting, which answers are particularly illuminating, etc.) for each answer. Keep it to a small number, e.g. 20.

What do you think? Anyone interested in participating in such a thing? Should this site be a part of SO, or should it be free standing. I'm willing to do a lot of the legwork required.

EDIT: It seems I didn't make the question clear. I'm not talking about search options to list questions with most votes. What I have in mind is *selected* list of questions with some commentary, kind of like [this one](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2010/08/05/Interesting+answers+on+Stack+Overflow+from+July) (although with more useful comments).

Comment: Get 10,000 rep and check http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last7days.

Comment: :-) The intent here was for everyone to benefit from these commentaries.

Comment: What say me? Me say this: [Ninja search options!](http://stackoverflow.com/search)
Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3a1%20votes%3a10&tab=newest).

Comment: @gnovice, ninja search options will only get you so far, SEDE did a lot of the work here.

Answer (score 1):

How **dare** you mock Waffle's commentaries!! :) On that topic, I was kind of burnt out after hand selecting those posts, it took me a couple of hours. I wanted the focus to be on the links and not the commentary.

A lot of this list was hand picked from this query:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/421/interesting-answers-per-tag-in-the-last-n-days

I looked for high voted, longish non-wiki answers. Except for wycats's answer which should not be wiki anyway.

I think a monthly staff picked top 10 list per month on the SE blog would be a great idea, we used to do something similar in the podcast.

More importantly though I would like the site to do a better job at finding these gems, we are talking about re-designing a tag section to include (stats / info / answers / questions) which would allow people to easily hone in on great answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The comment about your commentaries was more about the fact that they were very brief <blush>. So you think this is a good idea? What can I do to make this happen, you think? Such a site would really be helpful for people like me who are at the beginning of a long road.